# .NET MVC Dispatcher by Host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Suppose my site (a.com) serves different client. Each client has its own sub-domain:
    first.sub.a.com
    second.sub.a.com
    third.sub.a.com

each subdomain is coupled in our db with a specific url for this client:

```
first.sub.a.com -> a.com/sites/1
second.sub.a.com -> a.com/sites/2
third.sub.a.com -> a.com/sites/3
```

What would be the best way to create a forwarding mechanism for this? 
I can't really use urlrewrite because subdomains are added dynamically (route 53), and I don't want to change the iis configuration every time it happens.

I thought I would do the following:

- Point each subdomain entry using urlrewrite to forward to a specific controller action
  For example every *.sub.a.com request should be redirected to
  a.com/dispatcher
- On the dispatcher controller i check the host request and try to find a match in the db.
- Once found I return the result of the url that is coupled.

Is there a better way to do this?
The website url in the browser should stay as entered, that's why I can't really redirect urls.